# Best online app for importing, viewing and editing mpp project files?

Tags: webapp-rec

What is the best online application for importing Microsoft Project Files (file extension: .mpp)?

To view and then to further edit.  A bonus would be able to then export after edits back into .mpp format.

So far I've found [Gantter.com](http://www.gantter.com/) and [projec.to](http://www.projec.to/) but would like to hear from someone who's experience of these or others.

Comment: @Al done, it was specific for me in that I had an mpp I needed to open yesterday but I hear you.

Answer (score 3):

There is [GANTTzilla.com](http://www.ganttzilla.com/).

> **Upload & View:** Open your Microsoft Project and Planner files right in the
>   web browser!
>
> **Edit:**  Edit projects using Gantt or PERT views. And yes, we do version
>   control for your documents ;)
>
> **Export:**  Use converters to quickly export documents into other project
>   formats as well as PDF or PNG.
>
> **Share:**  Share your project with colleagues and team members or publish
>   the document so the whole world can
>   see it.
>
> **Track:**  Report, comment and track project progress in Gantt. It's quick,
>   easy and fun!

Comment: GANTTzilla.com is not working now.. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/ganttzilla/?platform=online

Answer (score 0):

Tried many various application for these manipulations, stopped at fix project

Utility is able to make all these things and even recover mpp files in case of some troubles

http://www.project.fixtoolboxx.com